# How to be sure that the $k$th largest singular value is at least 1 of a matrix containing a k-by-k identity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

In section 8.4 of the report of [ID software](http://cims.nyu.edu/~tygert/id_doc.pdf), it says that the $k$th largest singular value of a $k \times n$ matrix $P$ is at least 1 if some subset of its columns makes up a $k\times k$ identity.

I tried to figure it out but couldn't be sure of that. Any ideas on how to prove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The middle part of the SVD (which containts the singular values) does not change if you permute columns, so you may put the $k$ columns mentioned first. So assume the matrix has the form $A=[\begin{smallmatrix}I&B\end{smallmatrix}]$ where $I$ is a $k\times k$ identity, and $B$ is $k\times(n-k)$. Compute $$AA^T=I+BB^T\ge I$$
and conclude that eigenvalues of $AA^T$ are all at least $1$.

Comment: Would you please clarify the point that the eigenvalues of $AA^T$ are all at least 1 if $AA^T\geq I$?

Comment: And I don't understand why SVD does not change. I see that the singular values remain the same but I think $U$ and $V$ change.

Comment: If $B\ge I$ then $x^TBx\ge\lVert x\rVert^2$ for any vector $x$. Now let $x$ be an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda$ and plug it in.

Comment: Ups, you're right that the SVD does not change. I'll correct that.

Comment: I see the point now. And the eigenvalues are the square of singular values. So the singular values are also at least 1. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yep. You're welcome.